# What is the meaning of "size of an widget"?

Tags: qt4

I am learning UI programming using QT and i am bit confused by what size of an widget means.

Is it the number of pixels? or does it literally mean size measured in inch, cm or something?

If it is measured in pixels, then isn't the actual size depends on the pixel density?

Comment: Mostly widget size is measured in pixels. Then you can optimize your app e.g. to fit on an 1200x1000screen and you know upscaling is no problem (down is).

Comment: The number of pixels would be a way of measuring the area of a widget. :) You probably want two numbers: width and height.

Comment: @InsertNickHere, when you say 1200x1000 screen, does it mean that all the devices with this resolution have the same physical size?

Comment: Actualy no. Its just the logical way to see a display. Your window may appear larger/smaller on certain monitory/screen resolutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt uses pixels as a measure for widget size; but it's hardly ever necessary to explicitly specify the size of a widget using pixels. Instead, use the provided functionality for [layout management](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/layout.html). This way, your application/dialog layout will easily scale to different window or display sizes.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on the **Window Geometry**. Check this one out.

[alt text http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/images/geometry.png](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/images/geometry.png)

More documentation can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/application-windows.html#window-geometry)..  Hope it helps..